# Negative cost coefficients in Transportation problem

Tags: optimization, optimal-transport

I have a minimum transportation cost supply demand matrix which looks like this , I dont know how to handle negative cost coefficients, since negative costs dont make any sense , should I just ignore them or add most negative value to all cells ? will it change the solution??

The literature I referred to says we should have non negative coefficients but is largely silent on what to do when we have negative coefficients

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
 & \text{S1} & \text{S2} & \text{S3} & \text{S4} & \text{S5} \\ \hline
\text{D1} & 4 & 7 & 0 & 3 & 6  \\ \hline 
\text{D2} & 1 & 2 & -3 & 3 & 8 \\ \hline
\text{D2} & 3 & -1 & 4 & 0 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: How does this problem arise (other than as a school assignment)?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone yes it is a school assignment (college actually ) and i ask forgiveness if the question sounds very rudimentary , but I was not able to find any good source which could justify what solution one must take in such cases . I would be highly obliged and thankful if you could tell me  the solution if you know it  :) thanks!

Comment: I am not seeking at explicitly solving the problem only just  a solution on how to tackle such cases , any help would be welcomed

Comment: Why not solve it as is?  You could directly enter it into a general purpose LP solver.  It seems to me that negative costs can make sense. For instance, maybe someone's willing to pay to move something in the form of their paying a rental fee for a one-way rental - that's a negative cost to the owner.

Comment: I actually got confused when I tried to cross check with this online tool , http://www.phpsimplex.com/ the developer has simply ignored the negative costs in finding basic feasible solution by Volge's approximation

Comment: None the less thanks for explanation ! :)